# Invariant Violation error FlatList in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use flatlist with api call in react-native but I get an error "tried to get frame or out of range index NaN". The response of api is array.

My flatlist is like below

```
<FlatList
      data={dataSource}
      renderItem={({ item}) => {  
      return (   
         <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "black" }}>
            {item.name}
         </Text>);
 }}
 />
```

My api call is like below

```
const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData =  () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(
              "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/united"
            );
            console.log(Array.isArray(response.data)); //true
            
            setDataSource({ dataSource: response.data });
            
            setLoading(false);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } 
        };
    
        getData();
      }, []);
```

What can I do to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useState` hook works differently from a class-based `this.setState()`.
Refer to the official documents for more information
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state

The correct syntax in your case would be

```
try {
    const response = await fetchData();
    setDataSource(response.data); // Array
    setLoading(false);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```